# imageresizer outputs image paths with query strings, Pingdom Tools suggest "Remove query strings from static resources" -- how?

Tags: imageresizer

Can image resizer output image paths that don't contain query strings? Could not find this anywhere in documentation or googling it.

This page (http://imageresizing.net/docs/extend/extending) says that custom plugins can "Perform URL rewriting or query string expansion by registering an event handler."

Is there such a plugin, ready to be used? If so, anyone have a link?

Answer (score 1):

[FolderResizeSyntax](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/folderresizesyntax) is one such plugin (which simply adds and event handler to `Config.Current.Pipeline.Rewrite`), but you probably shouldn't use it.

Ask yourself: *Why* does pingdom say to remove query strings? Does it even make sense? Is there any logic behind the rule?

Query strings are often added to static resources as cache breakers and for development purposes; often they're forgotten and make it into production.

In the case of ImageResizer, they're an essential, meaningful part of the URL. Rewriting consistent name/value pairs (the querystring) into a custom URL syntax *might* be trendy and hip, but **it adds brittleness and complexity for no actual added value.**

If you have a real-world, known issues with querystrings, [try the CloudFront plugin](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/cloudfront). It lets you express querystrings as `image.jpg;width=100;height=100` instead of `image.jpg?width=100&height=100`. You still lose compatibility with all kinds of RIAPI-compliant front-end and back-end tooling, so make sure this is a real, not theoretical, issue.

Comment: According to Pingdom, "Resources with a "?" in the URL are not cached by some proxy caching servers. Remove the query string and encode the parameters into the URL for the following resources". You also pointed out that query strings are used as cache breakers. My goal is to have all the images cached by all browsers, since they do not change. Having query strings in the URL is useful for ImageResizer, but not for browser caching. I want the have my cake and eat it, too :) Any possibility of that?

Comment: Most caching proxies nowadays simply follow the HTTP Caching standard, querystring or no. **NO** browsers have the behavior they describe. What they may have been referring to is that some CDNs drop querystrings by default - but can easily be configured to preserve them. Note that the [CloudFront plugin was created to solve this problem](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/cloudfront) - back when it still was a problem. It lets you use a semicolon-delimited syntax instead of ? and &. Still, pingdom is giving you bad advice here.

Comment: It does not look like IIS can output expiration headers on content with query strings in the URL. Does that not prevent browser caching of said content?

Comment: IIS can most definitely output expiration headers on requests with query strings. We've tested with IIS 5.1, 6, 7, 7.5, and 8.

Comment: What are the exact entries that you're using in Web.config to output expiration headers on requests with query strings? Maybe I'm doing it wrong?